# Facing glitch while clearing menu from Bottom Navigation View Android

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview

I have inflated .xml menu file to bottom navigation view in activity. After click instance I'm clearing old menu and passing new menu.xml file to inflate.

It is working fine but forclearing menu I am using

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomView);
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().clear();
```

While clearing menu it is giving some glitch somewhat like flip animation before adding new menu. Can we disable menu clearing animation somehow?

Comment: Hi, facing same problem & condition here. Any solution yet? Thanks! :D

Answer (score -2):

You can try -

```
bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: If GONE was option then why I will inflate new menu? I want to replace old menu with new menu.xml after click event. Don't want to hide it.